# Sending Declared Strings as query to write in SQL Server Using .NET

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql-server

This is the demo code to a project I can't really get to send the "hisname" and "hisage" declared variables as a query. I actually need to send a query for each time the user enters the name and age those names and age must be sent as a query to the database.

```
static void Main()
    {
        string hisname;
        int hisage;


        Console.WriteLine("Hello! Have you met a new friend?");
        string ans = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
        if (ans == "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Amazing! Whats his Name?");
            hisname = Console.ReadLine();                                                    
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Whats his age?");
            hisage = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want me to store it?");
            Console.ReadLine();
            string ans2 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ans2 == "y")
            {
                string SQLConnectionString = "Server=tcp:MYSERVER.database.windows.net,1433;Database=friendsadded;User ID=MYID;Password=MYPASS;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
                // Create a SqlConnection from the provided connection string.
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                    command.Connection = connection;

                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [myfriends] ([Friend], [Age]) VALUES ( N'hisname', 'hisage')";
                //    command.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP 10 UID, FRIEND, AGE FROM dbo.myfriends";

                    connection.Open();
                         }
                    }
             }
       }
   }
}
```

Here the friendsadded is the database and myfriends is the table under it. I want it to add the names and age of the new entries to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of using parameters for this instead of passing through user entered data which is vulnerable to sql injection.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;

    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [myfriends] ([Friend], [Age]) VALUES ( @hisname, @hisage)";
    command.Parameters.Add("@hisname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value =  hisname;
    command.Parameters.Add("@hisage", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  hisage;
    connection.Open();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't recognize SqlDbType am I missing any class or reference?

Comment: That is in the System.Data namespace.

Comment: I am using that, but still it shows me the same error.

Comment: LOL. That is because there is a typo in the code I posted. One sec.

Comment: OK. I had a period after the parameter names so it was thinking that SqlDbType was a string property, which obviously it isn't. :D